# how to set background of table cell?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview

I have created tableview and set the text in cell lable, now i want to set background image in my cell and my lable will display on that image .how can i do that?

I have tried this but it does not work for me.

```
UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 500, 500, 500)];
av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
av.opaque = NO;
av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"];
cell.backgroundView = av;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `backgroundView` property of the `UITableViewCell` to an  `UIImage`, simply using:

```
theCell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_normal.png"]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the backgroundView . simply using the code below.

```
Cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Standard `UITableViewCell` styles and NOT any custom cell then apart from doing what you are already doing, you need one more step.

You must clear the background color of the label used by default `UITableViewCell` so for instance,if you are using `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` then you must also use

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The default label tends to hide the background of cell.